# Know the performance of the smartphone

Tags: android, performance, sqlite

I'm working with the data generated with the sensor accelerometer. I save every sensor event in sqllite. I don´t have any problem With smartphones like Nexus 5 but with old devices, I think that not all the registers are being recorded in the database because the smartphone doesn´t have enought capacity.
I'm thinking in save all the sensorevent in an array and then save all of them with a transaction, but only for the old devices. How can I know the capacity of a smartphone or at least the year?
Thanks,
Manuel

Comment: Why don't you want to batch the inserts even on better hardware? Getting the CPU/IO load down is always nice.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The application is still not stable and I need to ensure that some information is saved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple options. For example you might:

1. You may check for old android Versions like Gingerbread, which are usally old devices
2. You can get the CPU specs ([link](http://www.roman10.net/how-to-get-cpu-information-on-android/))
3. Do a quick benchmark by yourself. E.g. perform some simple sql tasks and measure the time, when you start your app the first time.
4. You can check the Device Name via Build.DEVICE ([link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#MODEL))

There might be an other way. These are just ideas which came to my mind while reading your question.